# How i can have my table responsive on mobile?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to render my table responsive but i have a marge. I put the table-responsive but even with that it doesn't work.

i did exactly the same for an other page and it works . Not for this one, weird !

```
<Container className='dataContainer' fluid>
      <Row>
        <Col>
        <h3>Base de données client</h3>
        </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row >
        <Table class="table-responsive" striped hover>
        <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nom</th>
        <th>Prenom</th>
        <th>Mail</th>
        <th>Numero</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {this.display()}
        </tbody>
        </Table>
     </Row>
       
      
</Container>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Bootstrap? If so, you need a div around table tag with class="table-responsive".

Like this:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table">
</table>
</div>
```

Css looks like this:

```
.table-responsive {
display: block;
width: 100%;
overflow-x: auto;
}
.table{
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @WendyMontagnon why "fluid", "striped" and "hover" are not inside the class tag? Maybe that's the problem?